# Cannot access MySQL container in VPS from MySQL Workbench In My PC

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-20.04

I've created a docker container that runs MySQL on it and exposes it on the default port (3306) on a DO droplet (Ubuntu 20).

I tried accessing it on my laptop with the following parameters:
Hostname: (VPS's IP address. I also tried Public Gateway IP)
Connection: Standard (TCP/IP)
Port: 3306
Username: root
Password: (Password I have set while creating the container)

The error message just says "Could not connect to localhost"
Am I missing a step that maybe exposes the container to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours, I found out that the `docker run` command has to have -p parameter. `-p=3306:3306` in my case.